# Use list of titles of custom post type as values for ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I would like to add a 'Post Author' select option in my Wordpress posts. Instead of creating 30 or so different users in Wordpress I would like to populate an ACF dropdown select field with all the titles of a custom post type (staff).

I found this code for outputting a list of custom post type titles...

```
 // query for your post type
$post_type_query  = new WP_Query(  
array (  
    'post_type'      => 'your-post-type',  
    'posts_per_page' => -1  
)  
);   
// we need the array of posts
$posts_array      = $post_type_query->posts;   
// create a list with needed information
// the key equals the ID, the value is the post_title
$post_title_array = wp_list_pluck( $posts_array, 'post_title', 'ID' );
```

...and I found this code from an ACF article about dynamically populating a select box...

```
function acf_load_color_field_choices( $field ) {

// reset choices
$field['choices'] = array();


// get the textarea value from options page without any formatting
$choices = get_field('my_select_values', 'option', false);


// explode the value so that each line is a new array piece
$choices = explode("\n", $choices);


// remove any unwanted white space
$choices = array_map('trim', $choices);


// loop through array and add to field 'choices'
if( is_array($choices) ) {

    foreach( $choices as $choice ) {

        $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;

    }

}


// return the field
return $field;

}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=color', 'acf_load_color_field_choices');
```

...however I'm really not sure how to splice the two together so that it grabs my custom field titles and adds them to that ACF field selector.

I tried but couldn't get any results to display.

Any ideas?

Comment: with ACf you can create a field with type "relation", and you select the custom post type below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from [mmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983864/mmm) I was able to use the 'Relationship' field type in ACF to achieve what I wanted... here is my code for anyone interested

'post-author' is the name of the ACF field, which was set to relationship, and the custom post type 'staff' was selected from the options, so I can choose any member of staff. They are then outputted in the post with thumbnail and job title...

```
<?php

$posts = get_field( 'post-author' );

if ( $posts ): ?>

<?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
<?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div class="author">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('small'); ?>
<div class="author-text">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    <p>
        <?php the_field('job_title') ?>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```